# Need help with solving a system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, least-squares, pseudoinverse

Given $n$ samples of vectors $\vec{x}\in R^k$ and n corresponding ground-truths $\vec{y}\in R^k$

I need to find the least square solution $A\vec{x}+\vec{b}=\vec{y}$ i.e. solve for $A$ and $\vec{b}$

Can someone please assist?

Thanks

Comment: Are $A$ and $b$ anything? Or are there constraints you don't tell like $A$ is actually a rotation/orthogonal matrix for instance ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Im looking for an affine transformation from $\vec{x}$ to $\vec{y}$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $A$ is any $k \times k$ matrix, you can flatten all its terms this way (for readability: example for k=2):

$$
\underbrace{
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1^1 & x_2^1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & x_1^1 & x_2^1 & 1 \\
x_1^2 & x_2^2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & x_1^2 & x_2^2 & 1 \\
& & ...
\end{pmatrix}
}_M
\underbrace{
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} \\
a_{12} \\
b_1 \\
a_{21} \\
a_{22} \\
b_2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
}_y
=
\underbrace{
\begin{pmatrix}
y_1^1 \\
y_2^1 \\
y_1^2 \\
y_2^2 \\
...
\end{pmatrix}
}_h
$$

Superscript refers to the number of the sample and subscript the item index in the vector.

You could then solve this system using classical least square methods or by [pseudo-inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) ($y = M^\dagger h$)